# How to convert $x^2-y^2-z^2 = 1$ to spherical equation?

Tags: calculus, spherical-coordinates

I was asked to convert $x^2-y^2-z^2=1$ to spherical coordinate equation.

What I do is substitute $x = \rho \sin(\varphi)\cos(\theta)$, $y = \rho \sin(\varphi)\sin(\theta)$ and $z = \rho \cos(\varphi)$ to get the equation:
$$(\rho \sin(\varphi)\cos(\theta))^2 - (\rho \sin(\varphi)\sin(\theta))^2 - (\rho \cos(\varphi))^2=1$$
Then I simplify it into:
$$\rho^2 \sin^2(\varphi) \cos(2\theta) - \rho^2\cos^2(\varphi) = 1$$
But when I submit it in Webassign, they still mark it wrong. I only have 1 submit left so I am very apprecitated if someone point out what I did wrong. Thank you!

Comment: You can probably further simplify with $\cos^2 x=1-\sin^2 x$.

Comment: Usually in spherical coordinates the angle between $\hat z$ and $\vec r$ is $\theta$, so you would need to switch $\theta$ and $\phi$ in your equations. Also, one can write $x^2-y^2-z^2=2x^2-\rho^2$

Comment: The conventions about $\theta$ and $\varphi$ are different in math and physics.  OP seems to be using the usual convention in math, and @Andrei is using the physics convention.

Comment: @DanVelleman Thanks. I found out something new today :)